# How to convert List to LazyList?

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

How to make a list lazy, i.e. create a LazyList given a usual one? I tried to find suitable method in Scala documentation, but there is no such function.

Comment: `list.to(LazyList)` - in any case, what is the point? it is already computed.

Comment: `myList.view` will create a lazy `SeqView` so that future traversals will be lazy.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to convert a List into a LazyList? There's no use of that laziness now

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Lazy computations using the list as input? 
 List(1,2,3,...,100).to(LazyList).map(veryExpensiveComputation).foldLeft(...).takeUntil...

Comment: @JamesMoore sure, although using `view` or `iterator` would have been better in this case. That is why I asked OP what was the end goal.

Comment: You want to convert a List into a LazyList so that transformations done afterwards have the LazyList semantics (memoized and lazy)

Comment: Use case: I have a List[java.io.Path] which you want to turn into a LazyList[Json] by reading the files to subsequently do various transformation on the Json that does not depend on the other input files/paths.

Comment: Another non XY problem use case: You need to use a third party library that expects only a LazyList

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to unpack the list into a LazyList. For example:

`LazyList(List(1,2,3) :_*)`