# Is there any benefit of converting a List to a LazyList in Scala?

Tags: scala

Is there any gain from converting a List to a LazyList in Scala?

For example:

```
val x = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

// This is supposed to save more memory in the long term
val y = x.to(LazyList)
```

A colleague I work with says that it reduces the amount of memory being used.

However, in my mind, the List is already loaded into memory. Doesn't that mean all the values have already been computed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert List to LazyList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63180931/how-to-convert-list-to-lazylist)

Comment: @GastónSchabas No, I know how to convert it already. I'm asking if there's a benefit to converting it. ie: In terms of memory, computation speed, etc.

Comment: There is a discussion in the comments of that post detailing what else you can do instead of calling the `to` method from `List`

Comment: I saw that - I'm not looking for an alternative. I'm just asking if there is any benefit to converting a List to a LazyList. There were people in the comments arguing for both sides. It didn't seem like there was a consensus.

Comment: Comments on the other post seem to agree to me: there's benefit only if you do something afterwards with the list that benefit from it being lazy. Otherwise, no benefit.

Comment: If you have a strict collection you already have everything in memory, converting that into a `LazyList` will not help that much. Usually you may rather start with a `LazyList` to avoid having all in memory from the beginning. But, that only makes sense if you both need it and know how to use the `LazyList` properly. In other words, IMHO, just keep using a `Vector` or whatever strict collection you want unless you really need something lazy.